# Installing Ubuntu Core on KVM - problem whith SSH

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core

I tried to install Ubuntu Core on KVM, but after installing Ubuntu Core I have no user that I can use to run commands.

[image: screenshot of QEMU]

And when I want to `ssh` it shows this:

[image: screenshot of SSH]

Comment: Hello Abolfazl Ebadi,  and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? And please insert command lines and command line output as plain text, instead of images.

Comment: It's trying to ssh to port 7010? It looks like something is wrong with your local ssh configuration. Look at your local `$HOME/.ssh/config` file.